# I cannot convert a '2D array whit bool' to a 'void 2D array bool'(for game of life)

Tags: c++, function

When I put my functions inside the main it say that:
73  44  C:\Users\Gaia\OneDrive\Documents\Gameoflife.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'bool (*)[g]' to 'bool (*)[20]' for argument '1' to 'void cambiamentoMappa(bool (*)[20])'
74  39  C:\Users\Gaia\OneDrive\Documents\Gameoflife.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'bool (*)[g]' to 'bool (*)[20]' for argument '1' to 'void ScambioMappa(bool (*)[20], bool (*)[20])'

I've searched up this error but found nothing and I haven't learned how to fix this in school

It should launch and start showing the Game of Life map evolving

Comment: What language is this? `main()` without a return type is C89, in which things like `#include <iostream>` don't exist.

Comment: Oh It's C++ sorry for not mentiong that

Comment: In C++ you should use `int main()`.

Comment: Okay now there is int main() but the error is still there

Comment: What compiler are you using? Which version?

Comment: I'm using Dev-C++ 5.9.2

Comment: @CappellatoMatteo That's an IDE not a compiler.

Comment: I don't think ScambioMappa does what you wanted it to do. Currently it just copies out of range ([g][g]) element into out of range element ;) Also `bool MatriceA[g][g]` doesn't look like a proper signature to me.

Comment: I've noticed that you are assigning the variable `g` to 20 but then overwriting this with user input, but then throughout the code, treating it as though it still has a value of 20 in it! I presume the locally declared `g` will override the globally assigned `g` which means if someone enters the value of 10, then most of your code will be writing to memory that isn't part of the array.

Comment: Also this might be useful post if you are copying the array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699152/what-is-the-fastest-portable-way-to-copy-an-array-in-c

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: your code is ill-formed.
Your compiler accepts some ill-formed parts of your code as an extension,
but that in turn triggers other ill-formed constructs.

---

Your code included the following line:

```
const int g = 20;
```

Later, in the `main` function, your code included the following line:

```
int g;
```

The latter *shadows* the former.
Then you attempted to declare an array:

```
bool MatriceA[g][g];
```

In C++,
the dimension of an array shall be a constant expression.
Here, `g` is a variable that is not a constant expression.
Variable-length arrays are not permitted in C++.
Therefore,
your code is ill-formed.

---

Since you are using the Dev-C++ *IDE*,
you are probably using the GCC *compiler*. 
GCC accepts variable-length arrays as an extension.
But then, you code doesn't compile either.

Your functions accept `bool MatriceA[g][g]` as a function parameter.
At that time, `const int g = 20;` is in effect.
Therefore, your function parameter is really `bool MatriceA[20][20]`,
which is really `bool (*MatriceA)[20]` because of function parameter decay
(see the Stack Overflow question [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432)).

Then you are calling the function with a variable-length array.
This is not allowed.
Therefore, your code is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling your function cambiotoMappa with two parameters, MatriceA and MatriceB

```
cambiamentoMappa(MatriceA, MatriceB);         /* Two actual parameters */
```

But your function accepts only one parameter

```
void cambiamentoMappa(bool MatriceA[g][g])    /* One formal parameter */
```