# How does cblas_dcopy fare against memcpy_s and std::copy?

Tags: c++, performance, intel, memcpy, blas

There is a lot of discussion on the comparison between `std::copy` and `memcpy_s` in terms of efficiency in copying one array to another.
I'd like to know where Intel MKL's `cblas_dcopy` stands in all of this. On an Intel machine with MKL installed, how efficient would `cblas_dcopy` be compared to `memcpy_s` for doubles? Does it also depend on a compiler?

While I can run comparative benchmarks myself, is there any solid theoretical expectation that I could already rely on? Or has this always been about trial & error approach?
If I have a C/C++ code with lots of use of `memcpy_s`, would it be a bad idea to replace all of it with `cblas_dcopy`?

Same question extends to comparison between `std::fill_n` and `cblas_dcopy(size, val, 0, double*, 1)`.

Comment: Last time I [did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50934364) such a benchmark on my machine, I found no difference at all between `memcpy` and `cblas_?copy`.

Comment: Are you doing small to medium sized copies with the source and/or destination hot in cache?  Or large copies that miss in cache all the way to DRAM?  The optimal strategy is different for those cases, and memcpy implementation may switch to using NT stores above a certain size limit.  Different implementations may use different strategies, so there's no reason to expect one to be globally optimal.

Comment: @PeterCordes those would be large vectors, I assume. Otherwise there is no need for me to optimize something negligibly small.

Comment: @MajinSaha: That's not generally true.  A program that calls memcpy millions of times for medium-sized copies (like 8KiB or something) is just as important as one that calls memcpy once for a 1GiB copy.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see. Let's say it's inside a general library for HPC operations, with no estimate on how and where exactly it may be used.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if some implementations of `cblas_?copy` just call memcpy, and so do compilers for `std::copy` with large or unknown-size copies.  So use whichever is most natural for the code; std::copy is your go-to option if you're already using C++-style code, otherwise if you're writing more C-style code you might just call memcpy.  In most implementations you're probably getting the same code anyway, but you could benchmark or reverse-engineer, e.g. single-step into them to see if they're ultimately using `memcpy` and if not whether they use different strategies.

Comment: Try and minimize the number of calls to memcpy period. Try and allocate as much memory beforehand.